# InvalidDeploymentParameterKey when using overrideParameters on an ARM deployment from Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-pipelines

Here is an extract from a YAML pipeline in Azure DevOps:

```yaml
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    name: GetAppInsightsConnString
    displayName: 'Get AppInsights ConnectionString'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.TelemetryAzureSubscription }}
      scriptType: 'pscore'
      scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
      inlineScript: |
        az extension add -n application-insights
        az feature register --name AIWorkspacePreview --namespace microsoft.insights
        $resourceInfo = az monitor app-insights component show --app ${{ parameters.AppInsightsResourceName }} --resource-group ${{ parameters.AppInsightsResourceGroupName }}
        $instrumentationKey = ($resourceInfo | ConvertFrom-Json).InstrumentationKey
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ApplicationInsightsInstrumentationKey]$instrumentationKey"
  - task: FileTransform@2
    displayName: "Replace Parameters From Variables"
    inputs:
      folderPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
      xmlTransformationRules: ''
      jsonTargetFiles: '**/${{ parameters.ArmTemplateParameters }}'
  - powershell: 'Get-Content $(Pipeline.Workspace)/${{ parameters.ArtifactName }}-provisioning/${{ parameters.ArmTemplateParameters }}'
    displayName: 'Preview Arm Template Parameters File'
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: "TEMP: Test new variable values"
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        Write-Host "ApplicationInsightsInstrumentationKey: $(ApplicationInsightsInstrumentationKey)"
  - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
    inputs:
      deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
      ConnectedServiceName: ${{ parameters.AzureSubscription }}
      action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
      resourceGroupName: ${{ parameters.ResourceGroupName }}
      location: $(locationLong)
      templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
      csmFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/${{ parameters.ArtifactName }}-provisioning/${{ parameters.ArmTemplate }}'
      csmParametersFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/${{ parameters.ArtifactName }}-provisioning/${{ parameters.ArmTemplateParameters }}'
      overrideParameters: '–applicationInsightsInstrumentationKey "$(ApplicationInsightsInstrumentationKey)"'
      deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
```

This is connecting to an App Insights instance, getting the instrumentation key, then doing a variable replacement on an ARM parameters file before previewing it and deploying it.

The instrumentation key is writtent to a `ApplicationInsightsInstrumentationKey` pipeline variable, and you can see a later task which previews this in the pipeline logs so I can confirm the variable is being set as expected.

On the final task I'm using an `overrideParameters` option to feed this key into the deployment as the value of the `applicationInsightsInstrumentationKey` parameter. This is where the pipeline fails, with the error:

> ##[error]One of the deployment parameters has an empty key. Please see https://aka.ms/resource-manager-parameter-files for details.

My web searching tells me this can occur when the value has spaces and isn't enclosed in double-quotes, but neither of those are the case here. In fact I can even replace that line with a hard-coded value and I still get the same issue.

If I remove that `overrideParameters` line the deployment succeeds, but obviously the parameter I want isn't included.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

As shown by the help dialog on ARM template deployment [ADO task](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeploymentV3/README.md):

[image]

Since, `applicationInsightsInstrumentationKey` will not have multiple words, try changing line like below:

```
overrideParameters: '–applicationInsightsInstrumentationKey $(ApplicationInsightsInstrumentationKey)'
```

Comment: Thanks, but no. Even if I hard code the value to a simple alpha string the task fails.

Comment: And make sure `ApplicationInsightsInstrumentationKey` is populated correctly with the value.

Comment: Is the value of ApplicationInsightsInstrumentationKey echoing correctly in the console?

Comment: Yes, you can see from the penultimate task prefixed `TEMP` that I'm writing the variable to the pipeline log and have visually confirmed it's the correct value

Comment: Error message is in my original post

Comment: Check this out: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/one-of-the-deployment-parameters-has-an-empty-key/1182405?viewtype=solutions Make sure the file encoding is UTF8 as we are using dash in instrumentation key

Comment: I've actually now moved on from this. Took a different approach. I think the issue may be related to encoding, yes, but I'm not able to confirm now. Thanks anyway.